# How to adjust the image inside anchor tag such that it does not comes out of the content area of anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have taken a image tag inside anchor tag and a button beside the anchor tag. I want to display a pic using the image tag but I am getting issue with the placement of the image. It is moving upwards and not getting displayed in the same line of the button. Please help me with the CSS.

```css
#divSelect a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.pic {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divSelect">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddl1", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
        @Html.DropDownList("ddl2", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return Submit()" /> <a href="@Url.Action("TEST", "Home")"><img class="pic" src="@Url.Content("/Images/pic.png")" width=30 height=30 /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since the link is an `inline-block`, you can use `vertical-align` on it to offset the image by positive/negative pixels, or use a preset value like `top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display in the same line, wrap your `button` and `anchor` in a `div`. Hope this will help you.

```css
#divSelect a {
  margin-left: 5px;      
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pic {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.select-inner{
  display:block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divSelect">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddl1", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
    @Html.DropDownList("ddl2", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
    <div class="select-inner">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return Submit()" /> 
       <a href="@Url.Action("TEST", "Home")"><img class="pic" src="@Url.Content("/Images/pic.png")" width=30 height=30 /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Check this image]

Comment: No its not working. The image is still on upper side and not in the line of the button.

Comment: Edited my answer add these CSS `.#divSelect a{vertical-align: middle;}` and `.select-inner{margin-top: 5px;}` also add a screen how it's look with image.